# How to access Layout Builder blocks in nodes quickly?

Tags: blocks, 10, layout-builder

Core version **10.1.6**. with Olivero theme.

My problem is that accessing layout builder blocks, especially in nodes, takes me much time. For example, my homepage has several large `"Hero"/"Highlightened"/"Navigation"/"Content Above"` blocks and if I click this node's **Layout** button I then land on the **top part** or **fold** of the webpage and then I have to scroll down all the way down to the relevant Layout Builder block and it's just ... tiresome ... to this time and again.

Is there a way, a hack, a module, anything, to access a Layout Builder block directly in-place and quickly?

Comment: Did you look at any of the contributed modules for Layout Builder? Frankly you have to be in the Layout mode to enable the editor and then every block can be edited in line.

Comment: Kevin I went through [an entire list of modules about Layout Builder](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_module?f%5B0%5D=&f%5B1%5D=&f%5B2%5D=&f%5B3%5D=&f%5B4%5D=sm_field_project_type%3Afull&f%5B5%5D=&f%5B6%5D=&text=layout+builder&solrsort=score+desc&op=Search) and yet I didn't find anything that does what I need to do.

Comment: Layout mode lets you edit blocks inline... either in the tray by default or using one of the modal modules for layout builder.

Comment: Kevin I don't know what specifically you mean to because I have tried "Layout Builder Modal" and didn't get "pencil icon" shortcuts to edit each Layout Builder block individually directly and quickly, and also, the other module "Layout Builder iFrame Modal" is not something I need because no `iframe` is involved here.